# Plot means basing on N rows before and after an event in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, aggregation

I have a data that looks like this:

```
"A" "B"
3 0
2 1
3 0
3 1
4 0
3 0
3 0
3 1
3 1
3 0
3 1
```

B is the event that may happen or not on each day (B==1 - event happened, B==0 - event did not happen), A is a measured variable, each rows is a day, data is in time order. I need to plot means for each of the N days before and after as function of whether the event happened (B==1) or not (B==0). Is there a function somewhere that can do this so I won't need to create new variables for each day before and after, reshape, etc.?

Comment: Your question is terribly unclear. Are these values in time order? If so, then since you say "B is the event" you're not talking about one event but many. Or are there two different kinds of event? The whole thing seems very confusing.

Comment: Sorry about that, @Glen_b. B is the repeating event (it may happen or not on each day). Values are in time order. I changed the text to make it more clear.

Comment: So when you say "the event" you mean "an event". How does one plot "rows" rather than values? What is it you want to plot, exactly? I presume it's something for *each* event in $B$.

Comment: I never said that I need to plot rows. 'A' is a measured variable so I need to plot means of 'A'.

Comment: Actually, you did. Look at the first three words of your title.

Comment: Well, you're right. I've changed it, hope it's more clear now. Anyway, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the function to do this turned out to be easier than I expected:

```
plot_n_bef_aft<-function(data, n=5){
      data<-data.table(data)
      for (i in c(1:n)) {
        data[, paste0('A','.-',i):= c(rep(NA,i), A[seq_len(.N-i)]), with=F]
        data[, paste0('A','.',i):= c( A[seq_len(.N-i)+i],rep(NA,i)), with=F]
      }
      data[,'A.0':=A, with=F]
      datar<-reshape(data,varying=c('A.0', paste0('A','.-',c(1:n)),paste0('A','.',c(1:n))), direction='long')
      qplot(data=datar, x=time, y=A, stat='summary', fun.data=mean_cl_boot, color= factor(B), geom=c('pointrange','line'))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find it convenient to use the `filter` function to calculate the N-before and N-after values.

```
n <- 5
m <- 25
x <- 1:m
a <- 3 + round(rnorm(m))
b <- round(runif(m)^1.5)
plot(x, a, type="l", col=grey(.5))
fafter <- c(rep(1/n, n), rep(0, n + 1))
fbefore <- c(rep(0, n + 1), rep(1/n, n))
points(x[b==1], filter(a, fbefore)[b==1], col="red", pch="-")
points(x[b==1], filter(a, fafter)[b==1], col="blue", pch="+")
```

I've used the `b==1` condition to only show the filter results for the events, though the calculations are done for all time values, if that matters.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about filter.